# ROS Answers SE migration: SDF versions

Tags: ros, sdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gazebo version 2.2.6, Indigo

Hello, ROS Community!

I would like to ask you about SDF versions. Nowadays, I am confused what SDF version is appropriate for running .world files. The question is appeared when I got errors following gazebo tutorials. [Here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=model_population&cat=build_world) , the .world file used SDF version 1.5 and It gave me errors:

```
Error [Converter.cc:127] Unable to convert from SDF version 1.5 to 1.4
Error [parser.cc:697] XML Element[population], child of element[world] not defined in SDF. Ignoring.[world]
Error [parser.cc:688] Error reading element <world>
Error [parser.cc:348] Unable to read element <sdf>
Error:   Could not find the 'robot' element in the xml file
     at line 81 in /build/buildd/urdfdom-0.2.10+dfsg/urdf_parser/src/model.cpp
Error [parser_urdf.cc:2608] Unable to call parseURDF on robot model
Error [parser.cc:273] parse as old deprecated model file failed.
```

I looked other .world files that run without any problem.. The files is under SDF version 1.4.

I was surfing ROS answers and gazebo tutorials, I didnt get the right answer..
If you will look at the [resource](http://sdformat.org/spec), you will see versions 1.4, 1.5, 1.6 are available. But, there are exist higher version in [downloads](http://sdformat.org/download)

What the version can I use in order I will not have any errors in version discrepancy?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226087/sdf-versions/) by [dyupleks](https://answers.ros.org/users/22089/dyupleks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 200 on 2016-02-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tag `population` is only applicable in Gazebo 5 or higher, you can actually see this in upper right corner at the link you provided. I highly suggest you to move to the new versions of Gazebo (and ROS) if you want all of the options.

---

Originally posted by [yasagitov](https://answers.ros.org/users/23174/yasagitov/) with karma: 223 on 2016-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dyupleks](https://answers.ros.org/users/22089/dyupleks/) on 2016-02-09**:
Thank you for your reply. You helped me to understand my several problems. I didnt notice to the upper right corner ) The idea to reinstall ROS and Gazebo is not attractive for me now.. But, I think that I dont have another choice

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any way to use the population tag in Gazebo 2? I am forced to use ROS indigo + Gazebo2. Any possibilities? Any other way to achieve something similar?

---

Originally posted by [filipposanfilippo](https://answers.ros.org/users/21802/filipposanfilippo/) with karma: 21 on 2016-05-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dyupleks](https://answers.ros.org/users/22089/dyupleks/) on 2016-05-06**:
Unfortunately, it is not possible. Look at [sdf specification](http://sdformat.org/spec?elem=world&ver=1.4). You use sdf version 1.4 with Gazebo 2, but population tag is available from version 1.5 and higher (click on World button and try to find population tag for 1.4 and 1.5)